# Google cloud dataproc failing to create new cluster with initialization scripts

Tags: hive, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, metastore, cloud-sql-proxy

I am using the below command to create data proc cluster:

> gcloud dataproc clusters create informetis-dev
>   --initialization-actions “gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/hue/hue.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/ipython-notebook/ipython.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/tez/tez.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/oozie/oozie.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/zeppelin/zeppelin.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/user-environment/user-environment.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/list-consistency-cache/shared-list-consistency-cache.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/kafka/kafka.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/ganglia/ganglia.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/flink/flink.sh”
>   --image-version 1.1 --master-boot-disk-size 100GB --master-machine-type n1-standard-1 --metadata "hive-metastore-instance=g-test-1022:asia-east1:db_instance”
>   --num-preemptible-workers 2 --num-workers 2 --preemptible-worker-boot-disk-size 1TB --properties hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=gs://informetis-dev/hive-warehouse
>   --worker-machine-type n1-standard-2 --zone asia-east1-b --bucket info-dev

But Dataproc failed to create cluster with following errors in failure file:

> cat 
>   + mysql -u hive -phive-password -e '' ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)
>   + mysql -e 'CREATE USER '\''hive'\'' IDENTIFIED BY '\''hive-password'\'';' ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on 'localhost' (111)

Does anyone have any idea behind this failure ?

Comment: please reformat the answer it's unreadable

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing the `--scopes sql-admin` flag as described in the [initialization action's documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/tree/master/cloud-sql-proxy#using-this-initialization-action), which will prevent the CloudSQL proxy from being able to authorize its tunnel into your CloudSQL instance.

Additionally, aside from just the scopes, you need to make sure the [default Compute Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#using_the_compute_engine_default_service_account) has the right project-level permissions in whichever project holds your CloudSQL instance. Normally the default service account is a `project editor` in the GCE project, so that should be sufficient when combined with the `sql-admin` scopes to access a CloudSQL instance in the same project, but if you're accessing a CloudSQL instance in a separate project, you'll also have to add that service account as a project editor in the project which owns the CloudSQL instance.

You can find the email address of your default compute service account under the [IAM page](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project) for your project deploying Dataproc clusters, with the name "Compute Engine default service account"; it should look something like `<number>`@project.gserviceaccount.com`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you already created the Cloud SQL instance with something like this, correct?

```
gcloud sql instances create g-test-1022 \
  --tier db-n1-standard-1 \
  --activation-policy=ALWAYS
```

If so, then it looks like the error is in how the argument for the metadata is formatted. You have this:

```
--metadata "hive-metastore-instance=g-test-1022:asia-east1:db_instance”
```

Unfortuinately, the zone looks to be incomplete (`asia-east1` instead of `asia-east1-b`).

Additionally, with running that many initializayion actions, you'll want to provide a pretty generous initialization action timeout so the cluster does not assume something has failed while your actions take awhile to install. You can do that by specifying:

```
--initialization-action-timeout 30m
```

That will allow the cluster to give the initialization actions 30 minutes to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you reported, it was detected an issue with [cloud sql proxy initialization action](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/356). It is most probably that such issue affected you.

Nowadays, it shouldn't be an issue.