# Dataproc Hive: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)

Tags: hive, google-cloud-dataproc

I am creating dataproc hive cluster with the following command.

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create hive-cluster \
    --scopes sql-admin \
    --image-version 1.3 \
    --master-boot-disk-size 15 \
    --num-workers 0 \
    --initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/cloud-sql-proxy/cloud-sql-proxy.sh\
    --properties hive:hive.metastore.warehouse.dir=gs://project-warehouse/datasets \
    --metadata "hive-metastore-instance=$PROJECT:$REGION:hive-metastore"\
    --initialization-action-timeout 30m
```

But initialization script fails with the error of "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111)"

When I ssh into the cluster I am able to connect to mysql thorough the command "mysql -h localhost -u root"

I followed this article : [https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910577/google-cloud-dataproc-failing-to-create-new-cluster-with-initialization-scripts)

I also given permissions as mentioned in this question.[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910577/google-cloud-dataproc-failing-to-create-new-cluster-with-initialization-scripts)

Answer (score 1):

We suspect the problem was that systemctl start cloud-sql-proxy might return asynchronously when the proxy server is not yet ready.

Confirmed fix in this PR waits until the proxy server is ready:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions/pull/356

Comment: Additionally, we've correlated this issue to an update the cloud-sql-proxy released upstream into dl.google.com on Sept 24th; anyone seeing failures of the init action without changing anything starting around Sept 24th is likely running into this same issue; syncing to the latest fix in the init action will resolve the issue in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue just recently. It seems like the script is failing to start the proxy before using the connection. I've also tested on Dataproc image 1.2 and the same issue occurred.

thanks

Comment: How recently did this start to happen for you? Were you also pointing to the latest version of cloud-sql-proxy.sh in gs://dataproc-initialization-actions, or were you pointing at your own static copy of it?

Comment: it happened almost a week ago and I pointed to the latest version of cloud-sql-proxy.sh